# radGrid filtering doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, telerik, filtering, radgrid

This is my code for telerik RadGrid

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="grdMain" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="0" EnableLinqExpressions="False"
 GridLines="None" PageSize="15"  AllowSorting="true"
 OnNeedDataSource="grdMain_NeedDataSource" 
 >
```

I have a text box `txtSearch` and a button to search and filter `grdMain` Grid .

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Search"
OnClick="search_Click" > 
</telerik:RadButton>
```

This is my click event

```
  protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

  grdMain.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "([ColumnOne] = '" + txtSearch.Text + "')";  
  grdAirLine.Rebind();
    }
```

But filtering in my Grid doesn't work . What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Apply filter in the code-behind.

To apply a filter in the code behind you need 3* things:
3*: Sometimes only 2.

1. **Set a filter filter expression**

   ```
    grdMain.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "([ColumnOne] = '" + txtSearch.Text + "')";
   ```

   This is the Expression the grid will filter on.
2. **Set your column current filter**
   This is *Only for the filter display* in your column header. This is just for *display* and *future filter*. However this Must be set or the grid will just ignore any filter expression.

   ```
   GridColumn column = RAD_Grid.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("ColumnOne");
   column.CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.EqualTo;
   column.CurrentFilterValue = txtSearch.Text;
   ```

> Needed only if is AllowFilteringByColumn is set on your `RadGrid` or `MasterTableView`.

3. **Rebind**

Rebind the grid you update the filter. If you are working with a nestedGrid rebinding the parent grid or every parent is sometimes needed.

> *The question code should be working once you rebind the correct grid.*

Answer (score -1):

You must add the ajax manager and the loading panel, this is how RadGrid filter the results.

Ex:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="grdMain">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdMain" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanelGrid" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanelGrid" runat="server" Height="75px"
    Skin="Office2007" Width="75px">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should look into telerik forums.

Here is the simliar kind of problem .
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-with-filtering-not-working.aspx